Help with identifying a problem with an electrect microphone amplifier circuit
I have been trying to make a USB microphone from a JLI-2555BXZ3-GP microphone capsule. This is my specific pre-amp design where V1 represents the electrect microphone. The JLI doesn't have an internal JFET so I chose to use a 2N4338. This is fed into a soon to be OPA1652AIDR (currently a ADA4897 I had lying around at the time and haven't bothered to resolder until I was sure I had a working circuit.) This goes into an ADC/USB grabber that also provides the 5 volt supply in this circuit.

The problem:
I have managed to get audio out of this circuit but it is terribly low volume and very noisy. It also has some very weird behavior where it only picks up my voice some of the time. Almost like the circuit has different "modes" it enters and leaves, one of which actually picks up audio. The microphone usually picks up audio after a low frequency noise oscillation (not always the case however.) I can sometimes trip the circuit into this "mode" by touching the gate of the JFET. (Is that damaging to the JFET?  This is my first time handling such sensitive JFETS.) The noise I kind of expected with the ADA4897 but I am simply at a loss for the lack of gain and the undefined behavior.
What I've tried so far:
I have tried using the JFET in a source follower configuration and with different resistor values with a potentiometer, all leading to more or less the same behavior. Although, surprisingly, the source follower configuration had about the same gain which I found curious (gain assumption purely based of volume of recording.) I have tried with and without R6 in the circuit (a Texas Instruments article left it out of the amplifier stage to my surprise) not much of a difference either.
I have access to an oscilloscope but have not really used it as of yet since I had no idea what I would want to look after but I am more than willing to test anything out that you might suggest.
I am really lost at this point and a little desperate to get this project done.

Why did you choose to use that microphone when you could have picked one with the JFET inside? Please also link to the data sheet for the microphone.

The microphone could be acting as an "open" for DC so the JFET isn't biased consistently. Or it could provide a DC voltage to the gate that is simply unsuitable. Did you check drain current or drain voltage?

https://www.jlielectronics.com/microphone-capsules/jli-2555bxz3-gp/ you can get a datasheet here. Trust me if i knew that is was commen practice at the time i would have never bought one without a internal jfet. But now im trying to do best with what i got

Did you use a resistor between the gate and ground of the JFET?

just checked real quick with a multimeter. Yeah the voltage is only around 30mV dc at the drain you might be on to something

I did not try a resistor between gate and ground. i assume you mean in parallel with the signal in. What size resistor would you suggest.

Some notes on your schematic: 1) Grounds point down, not sideways, not up. 2) If the 5V supplies are all from the same source you should model them as one source, ie remove V3 and V7, label the positive of V4 as something like "VCC" or "+5V" and then use that label to provide the other 5V connections.

Thank you all for your answers. I will definitely try the differential configuration Rohat Kılıç. And i really appreciate your effort Antonio51 although i don't fully understand it :). It turns out i was simply relying to much on my simulation. My JFET was quite far from its "ideal" behavior. Thank you Jos Bergervoet for tipping me of to this fact. There is still quite a large noise floor but i get consistent audio out now.

I'd try the differential configuration:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The output pair above should be fed to a differential amplifier.
But you can still get rid of R1 and C1 to make it source follower as suggested in the datasheet:

simulate this circuit

So i would connect C1 to in+ and C2 to in-? or maybe the other way around? Also would a 10nF cap suffice? i don't really have uF capacitors laying around.

@LizzyBoi So i would connect C1 to in+ and C2 to in-? or maybe the other way around? This should be fed into a differential amplifier because of the configuration itself. As for referring to the ends as + and –, it actually doesn't matter because it's AC-coupled. If you feed in the reversed order, the speaker's cone will pull instead of push. Fundamentally, no difference.

Okay thank you i will try this circuit instead i guess. I see you used a different JFET. Was that just for convenience or is it required for the differential setup? Thank you.

@LizzyBoi oh, sorry for using a different FET. It was there for reference. I'm removing the name now, you can use the one you have.

One last question. I have looked up some differential amplifiers and i see that you can make them with a op amp or with a couple of transistors. I was wondering which kind were you referring to?

@LizzyBoi doesn't matter but building one with an op-amp is easier. Keep the virtual ground in mind if you are about to power it with single-supply, just like you have done with your inverting amplifier as shown in your question. But single-ended solution is still there i.e. follow the second circuit and use your existing setup.

I changed JFET and drain resistor ... and the gain is a "bit" higher (3).
The output impedance of this stage is fairly "high", so
you would change using the +input of the OpAmp in place of the -input ...

Something like this:


Why the change in the op amp configuration? Also would there be any way to make the current JFET i have work? Shipping times for these kinds of components are very long to where i live.

Change of input is needed for high "impedance" following my C3 capacitor (impedance is 2 paralleled 1MegOhm= 500 kOhm). Otherwise, gain should be lower on "-input" (impedance should be 1 kOhm).
